# set div position to fixed after scrolling 100px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to use the following function in order to set the div's position to 100 px from top after scrolling 100 px.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#header").css("top",Math.max(0,100-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
</script>
<div class="header"  style="position:fixed;top:100px;background-color:red">something</div>
```

it is not working(the div stick to it's fixed position). it seems that the function is not relating to the div. what is my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem ist that your `div` has the `class` header, not the `id`. 
Try 
`<div id="header"  style="position:fixed;top:100px;background-color:red">something</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.header').scroll(function(){
        $(this).css("top",Math.max(0,100-$(this).scrollTop()));
    });
});
```