# Menu going down together with scrolling the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```css
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
        width: auto;
        /*    width: 200px;*/
        /*    font-weight: bold;*/
    }
    
    .mega-dropdown {
        position: static !important;
        /*    width: 100%;*/
    }
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu {
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #243C78;
        white-space: normal;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
        color: #243C78;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu form {
        margin: 3px 20px;
    }
    
    .mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="indexTop">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row indexTopPadding">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-11 ">
                        <div class="topData">Poniedziałek, 11 października 2019</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-1">
                        <div class="topKontrast">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon2.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft5"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon1.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft5"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 topMargin15 visible-xs">
                        <div class="topSocialMedia">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon7.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10 ikonSocialMediaR"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon3.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10 ikonSocialMediaR"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon4.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10 ikonSocialMediaR"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon5.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10 ikonSocialMediaR"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon6.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10 ikonSocialMediaR"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 topMargin30R ">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive ikonCenterR"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 topMargin10 hidden-xs">
                        <form method="post" name="contactformXX" class="form validate clearfix validate-form">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control indexInputSzukaj" id="inputValidation" placeholder="Znajdź" /> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphiconColor"></span> </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 topMargin15 hidden-xs">
                        <div class="topSocialMedia">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon7.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon3.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon4.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon5.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/ikon6.png" class="img-responsive topIkonLeft topIkonLeft10"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--    END TOP-->
        <!--    MENU-->
        <div class="paddingMenuTop"></div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbarDefaultMop ">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- navbar-fixed-top -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> <a class="navbar-brand  visible-xs" href="#">MegaMenu</a></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown menuMop"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Item xxx1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row dropdownMenuMop">
                                <div class="container topMenuColor">
                                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                                        <ul class="hideBullet">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header hideBullet">Sprawy  </li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">pozycja 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">pozycja 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">pozycja 3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">pozycja 4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">pozycja 5</a></li>
                                            <li class="dividerMop"></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-header hideBullet">pozycje 5</li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Bezpłatana imnformaja</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">dream</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Callendar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Archiwum Mewspow</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                                        <ul class="hideBullet">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header hideBullet">My life </li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Health</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Bicycles</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Cars</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Education</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Cash</a></li>
                                            <li class="dividerMop"></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-header hideBullet">Fundation</li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">xdcsdcsd cdscdscds</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Magazine</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Items</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Items2</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                                        <ul class="hideBullet">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header hideBullet">My life </li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Health</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Bicycles</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Cars</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Education</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Cash</a></li>
                                            <li class="dividerMop"></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-header hideBullet">Fundation</li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">xdcsdcsd cdscdscds</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Magazine</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Items</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="formattopMenuItems">Items2</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                                            <li class="dividerMop"></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                                            <form class="form" role="form">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"> </div>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                            </form>
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">zamknij mnie2
                                                <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I have a problem with the menu (NAVBAR).

I would like it to descend with scrolling the page down (stuck to the top of the browser).

The effect that I would like to get is here: https://www.gdynia.pl
Dla mieszkańców, aktualności, dla turystów, o Gdyni,

Does anyone know how to improve my code to get this effect?
Prview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/menu_fixed/

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? Did you look at the docs to see how to do this?

Comment: i have Bootstrap 3.4

Comment: Is there a reason you ignored the second half of my comment? Did you even look for something like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar-fixed-top)?

Comment: i not found this in docs. Menu when the page is loaded - is under the banner. It becomes glued together with scrolling the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to .navbar some other class with style like this: *position: fixed; top:0;* and **replace** *position:relative* with *position:fixed;*. 
- Add this class only after you scroll down some pixels. 
- If you not scrolled some pixels use remove or don't add class. 
- Use Javascript or JQuery to detect how many user already scrolled pixels and also to add or remove element class.
I think everything is clear here. I just opened your site and used chrome dev tools to see applied effects. Just play with code and styles. After apply changes in real code.
You can look more here: [set div position to fixed after scrolling 100px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341177/set-div-position-to-fixed-after-scrolling-100px)

Comment: yes, but my menu at the beginning is supposed to be below the banner - just like on gdynia.pl
Only when I scroll - this menu is to be "glued to the top of the screen".

See please gdynia.pl and tabs from the menu:dla mieszkańców, aktualności, dla turystów, o gdyni